# Django https ssl configuration error related to mod_wsgi

Tags: django, ssl, https, mod-wsgi

I deployed my Django project to AWS Linux AMI thought Elastic Beanstalk.
Currently, it works well with http, but on https, it shows an error like the below.

```
[:error] [pid 3090] [client 24.43.39.130:64135] Embedded mode of mod_wsgi disabled by runtime configuration: /opt/python/current/app/connectshops/wsgi.py
```

I've been struggling to debug the error but I can't figure it out yet.
Does anyone know what is wrong? Should I add some configuration on my ssl.conf file?

**EDIT**

**/opt/httpd/conf.d/wsgi.conf**

```
LoadModule wsgi_module modules/mod_wsgi.so
WSGIPythonHome /opt/python/run/baselinenv
WSGISocketPrefix run/wsgi
WSGIRestrictEmbedded On

<VirtualHost *:80>

  Alias /static/ /opt/python/current/app/static/
  <Directory /opt/python/current/app/static/>
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
  </Directory>


  WSGIScriptAlias / /opt/python/current/app/connectshops/wsgi.py


  <Directory /opt/python/current/app/>
    Require all granted
  </Directory>

  WSGIDaemonProcess wsgi processes=1 threads=15 display-name=%{GROUP} \
  python-home=/opt/python/run/venv/ \
  python-path=/opt/python/current/app:/opt/python/run/venv/lib64/python3.6/site-packages:/opt/python/run/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages user=wsgi group=wsgi \
  home=/opt/python/current/app
  WSGIProcessGroup wsgi
</VirtualHost>

LogFormat "%h (%{X-Forwarded-For}i) %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" comb$
```

This is the code in my wsgi.conf. As you said, I'm currently having WSGIRestrictEmbedded to be ON, but I'm not sure which one of them I'm using right now.
Just so you know, I have the same code for VirtualHost *:443

Comment: You have ``WSGIRestrictEmbedded`` to ``On`` to disable embedded mode, but haven't properly setup your configuration to have the WSGI application run in daemon mode. Show your Apache configuration for the WSGI application. Are you using ``WSGIProcessGroup`` directive, or ``process-group`` option to ``WSGIScriptAlias`` anywhere?

Comment: I guess I'm using WSGIScriptAlias, but I'm not sure since I'm very new to this part. If I have WSGIScriptAlias on it, should I remove WSGIRestrictEmbedded ?

Comment: @GrahamDumpleton I edited the posting to add my WSGI. Please check it out.

Comment: @GrahamDumpleton Like you asked, I'm using `WSGIProcessGroup`, `WSGIScriptAlias`, and `WSGIScriptAlias`. Should I remove all of them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using:

```
  WSGIDaemonProcess wsgi processes=1 threads=15 display-name=%{GROUP} \
      python-home=/opt/python/run/venv/ \
      python-path=/opt/python/current/app user=wsgi group=wsgi \
      home=/opt/python/current/app

  WSGIScriptAlias / /opt/python/current/app/connectshops/wsgi.py process-group=wsgi

  <Directory /opt/python/current/app/>
    Require all granted
  </Directory>
```

I don't see any specifically wrong with what you had, but have changed the order and used `process-group` instead of `WSGIProcessGroup`.

Also dropped directories from `python-path` which shouldn't need to be added.

Leave the `WSGIRestrictEmbedded` directive alone.

Comment: Should both ssl.conf and wsgi.conf have the same codes like the above? I made them to have the same codes but an error shows up saying "Name duplicates previous WSGI daemon definition." on WSGIDaemonProcess

Comment: Don't include a ``WSGIDaemonProcess`` in the second ``VirtualHost`` of the HTTP/HTTPS pair, but still use ``process-group=wsgi`` in second ``VirtualHost``. In that very special case where is same ``ServerName`` and port, mod_wsgi will allow you to reference the daemon process group defined in the first ``VirtualHost`` from the second. This is specially so that can share the one daemon process group for HTTP/HTTPS instances.

Comment: Okay, now it's perfectly working well. What I did is, on both sides of ssl and wsgi, they each have the same codes but they have different `WSGIDaemonProcess`'s names, and now it's totally working fine. Thank you @Graham. Since I was very new to this thing, everything was confusing to me, but you gave me a big clue to figure things out!

Comment: If you have separate ``WSGIDaemonProcess`` in each ``VirtualHost`` you are wasting memory as have two separate copies of your application when not needed. As I said, you can remove ``WSGIDaemonProcess`` from the second and use the name of the one from the first instead in the second and then they will both use the same one. This is the recommended setup.